# Is there a way to change the selected row background color of Silverlight DataGrid?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, row, background-color

I haven't found anything that works.

This is my code:

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="dgSample"
    Grid.Row="2"
    CanUserSortColumns="True"
    CanUserResizeColumns="False"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Path=App.TextAlignment,
        Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
    Foreground="Black"
    FontWeight="Normal"
    FlowDirection="{Binding Path=App.FlowDirection,
        Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
    AreRowDetailsFrozen="True"
    LoadingRow="dgSample_LoadingRow">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the `Template`, here's an example of a RowStyle you can use on a `DataGrid`. Tweak the colours and mouseovers to your requirements.

Use it like this ...

```
<sdk:DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource BetterHighlightedDataGridRowStyle}" />
```

Define it like this ...

```
<Style x:Key="BetterHighlightedDataGridRowStyle" TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
                    <sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid x:Name="Root">
                        <sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="DetailsVisibleTransition">
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContentHeight" Storyboard.TargetName="DetailsPresenter"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.Resources>
                        <sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NormalAlternatingRow">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NormalSelected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#DDE9EE33" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOverSelected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#E1C8C864" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnfocusedSelected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#DDE9EE33" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Invalid">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="InvalidVisualElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="#FFBADDE9" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="InvalidVisualElement" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="#FFF7D8DB" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                        <sdk:DataGridRowHeader x:Name="RowHeader" sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                        <sdk:DataGridCellsPresenter x:Name="CellsPresenter" Grid.Column="1" sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True"/>
                        <sdk:DataGridDetailsPresenter x:Name="DetailsPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BottomGridLine" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    </sdk:DataGridFrozenGrid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```